# Родовые окончания

Tags: грамматика, род, существительные, мягкий-знак

Как узнать род слова, заканчивающегося на мягкий знак? Я знаю только, что если мягкий знак стоит после шипящих, то это женский род. А как узнать остальные?

Answer (score 2):

Правила содержат *много исключений*, что на практике вызывает трудность определения рода существительного на **Ь**. Такие слова надо запоминать.

Есть некоторые советы и секреты.

1. Относятся к ***мужскому роду***:

названия месяцев (ноябрь, июль);
 большинство слов на **-арь** (псарь, звонарь, букварь);
 большинство слов на **-тель** (посетитель, укротитель, ваятель).

Исключения (что помню): *тварь, утварь, гарь, марь, обитель, канитель, метель, постель, капитель...*

2. Относятся к ***женскому роду***:

слова на **-чь, -шь, -щь** (ночь, мышь, вещь);
слова на **-ость**
(они образованы от прилагательных; сухой - сухость, мягкий - мягкость);
большинство слов на **-бь, -вь, -дь, -зь, -сь, -ть** (любовь, тетрадь, связь, спесь).

Исключения: *тесть, ноготь, нехристь, локоть, лапоть, коготь, дёготь, ломоть,  голубь, лебедь, гусь, лось, князь, дождь, вождь, груздь, гвоздь...*

3. Слова на **-ль, -нь, -рь** могут быть как мужского, так и женского рода.
4. Если Вам встретилось слово на **-ь** в тексте, обратите внимание на соседние слова, особенно прилагательные и глаголы в прошедшем времени.
   Например, вы читаете: *"Спортсмен получил золотую медаль"*. Слово "медаль" употреблено в винительном падеже, а прилагательное "золотую" — в винительном падеже и женском роде. Значит, слово "медаль" — это слово женского рода.
   Или:
   гать бы**ла** разруше**на**, сельдь съеде**на**, цель пораже**на** (ж.р.); дюбель бы**л** пласмассов**ый**, породист**ый** кобель пропа**л** (м.р.).

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: 1. **Всегда** относятся к мужскому роду.. **Исключения…** 2. **Всегда** относятся к женскому роду… **Исключения…**_ === 
Но почему же **всегда-то?** Ведь Вы же сами это "всегда" опровергаете, вводя списки исключений, да ещё заканчивающиеся к тому же многоточиями. И как узнать, какие слова скрываются за этими многоточиями?

Comment: "Куча" правил в русском языке имеет исключения.  Это НЕ правила, а одни из "помощников",  облегчительные рекомендации (как я их помню).  Добавляла исключения уже по ходу ответа. Если еще вспомню - припишу. P.S. Не дала бы исключений - Вы бы первый меня "поклевали".

Comment: _Это НЕ правила, а одни из "помощников"_ === Может, кому-то, сумевшему запомнить эти исключения **с многоточиями**, эти "помощники" и помогут, но... Но всё же: почему **"всегда"?** Может, более правильным было бы заменить "всегда" на "чаще"?

Comment: Да, скорее всего, Вы правы. Подкорректирую...  Хотя  во многих безапелляционных правилах есть и свои "цыгане", и свои "цыпочки".

Comment: @slava1947 Простите, что опять вмешиваюсь, но надеюсь, что в этот раз более удачно... *Может, кому-то, сумевшему запомнить эти исключения с многоточиями, эти "помощники" и помогут* - они реально помогают. Это рекомендации для преподавателей РКИ. Так учат и иностранцев - и сами иностранцы своим студентам так дают. Вопрос только в "моноготочиях", то есть в полноте списка. Помнится, для запоминания обычно предлагается 16-18 слов. Я вспомнил 17. Хотя, наверное, не все те, что рекомендованы. Но всё-таки список такой можно сделать достаточно полным для практической надобности.

Comment: Мне другое непонятно, зачем здесь отдельно поминать какое-то "правило" для слов на "ость", если и так известно, что все слова на Ть (за исключением стопроцентных мужчин зятя и тестя) - женского рода?! Только путает...

Comment: И ничего не путает. Для иностранца очень важно словообразование, поэтому обычно отдельно и выделяют существительные, взамосвязанные с прилагательными: верный - верность, липкий - липкость, вязкий - вязкость. Например, трость и жимолость - из другого "словообразовательного теста".

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: Исключения (что помню): тварь..._ === Ну, на _**арь**_ в русском языке в женском роде оканчивается не только _**тварь**_. Заглянув в словарь Зализняка, легко можно найти и _**киноварь**_, и _**утварь, гарь (+ изгарь, пригарь, огарь, выгарь), бездарь, марь, хмарь, старь...**_

Comment: Не каждый русский знает большинство из указанных Вами слов. Я кое-что добавлю в ответ, конечно. Но! Если "огарь" (утка), то это м.р., а "бездарь" допускает двойной род. Эта тема - бесконечна, объять всё и вся практически невозможно. Но ведь ОСНОВЫ-то мои верные?

Comment: Верными я бы их (может быть) считал, если б в них отсутствовали многоточия в конце перечней исключений. Но если кому-то многоточия помогают...

Answer (score 1):

Что можно предложить, кроме словаря (но словарь -  это самый верный способ):

1) Род можно определить по склонению и по сочетаемости с прилагательными, например:

тюль (м.р.) - занавески из тюлЯ,  прозрачнЫЙ тюль;

мозоль (ж.р.) - нет мозолИ,  любимАЯ мозоль.

2) Существуют разные эмпирические правила-наблюдения  для сущ. м.рода:

К м.р. относятся около 150 слов на СОНОРНЫЕ:  ль, нь, рь, из них:

все названия месяцев (октябрь, июнь);

слова на -арь (словарь, календарь);

слова на -тель (учитель, выключатель).

Также названия многих животных (рыб, птиц, зверей, насекомых).

Answer (score 0):

> Я знаю только, что если мягкий знак после шипящих, то это женский
>   род... **а как узнать остальные?**

С помощью словаря. Посетив, к примеру, сайт [**Грамота.ру**](http://www.gramota.ru/).

[**МОЗОЛЬ**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C&all=x), -и; **ж**.

[**ТЮЛЬ**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8C), -я; **м**.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. По "внешнему облику" эти слова не распознаешь. 
С ними путаются даже носители родного русского языка.
Более того, случается, что такие слова меняют грамматический род.

Помимо названного правила (все слова, заканчивающиеся на "шипящий + мягкий знак" - женского рода), есть только одно достаточно универсальное правило, которое может помочь. Все слова, обозначающее *человека* (профессию или действие), а так же *действующий агент*, образованные от глаголов с суффиксом "(т)ель" - мужского рода. *Писать - писатель, нагревать - нагреватель, носить - носитель, красить - краситель* - все мужского рода.

Но: *обитель* (это не человек), *канитель, капитель* - (не от глагола, это заимствованные слова) - женского.

Все остальные слова надо проверять по словарю.
Впрочем, основные слова мужского рода на мягкий согласный достаточно просто запомнить.

К словам мужского рода относятся

**Бь** - голубь
**Вь** - червь
**Гь** - (не бывает, ни мужского ни женского, фонетическое правило)
**Дь** - гвоздь, дождь, вождь, желудь, медведь, господь, груздь, лебедь
**Зь** - ферзь, витязь, язь
**Жь** - (только женского, орфографическое правило)
**Кь** - (не бывает, фонетическое правило)
**Ль** - Учитель, скальпель... (очень много и тех и других, мужского больше - см. выше).
**Мь** - (слов мужского рода нет)
**Нь** - Очень много слов мужского рода: конь, шампунь, камень, бюллетень, день, корень, парень, уровень, огонь, клубень, олень, женьшень, гребень, несколько производных слов на "ень" (лопатень, копытень, вытютень, выворотень, оборотень, выползень, баловень и подобные), несколько выходящих их употребления слов (гордень, гридень и подобные), линь, лунь, булинь, дюгонь, пень и ряд заимсвованных из восточных языков слов специфического значения (бань, юнь и проч.)...
**Пь** - (слов мужского рода нет)
**Рь** - зверь, монастырь, кенарь, кубарь, пастырь, секретарь, библиотекарь, виноградарь, фонарь, инвентарь, алтарь, пластырь, рыцарь, государь, словарь, богатырь, лагерь, лекарь, лодырь, календарь, бондарь, аптекарь (и еще много слов, обозначающих профессию или действующего агента по глаголам), упырь, корчмарь, нетопырь, поводырь, пономарь, волдырь, вратарь, букварь...  - слов очень много, в основном они мужского рода.
**Сь** - карась, лосось
**Ть** - зять, тесть, гость, путь
**Фь** - (только одно женского - верфь)
**Ць** - (не бывает, фонетическое и орфографическое правило)
**Чь, Щь, Щь** - (только женского, орфографическое правило)

Остальные слова на -ь скорее всего женского рода.

Итак.

1. Реально **необходимо проверять по словарю** слова на **Рь, Ль и Нь** - хотя огромное большинство из них мужского рода, причем с характерными суффиксами **арь/ырь, ень, (т)ель**.
2. Остальные слова мужского рода можно запомнить. **Голубь, червь, гвоздь, дождь, вождь, желудь, медведь, господь, груздь, лебедь, ферзь, витязь, язь, карась лосось, зять, тесть, гость, путь** - слова мужского рода. Список можно уточнить.
3. Остальные, не подпадающие под эти два пункта, оканчивающиеся на **Ь** слова - скорее всего женского рода (хотя для иностранца нелишним будет проверить и их по словарю).

Comment: На -ТЬ есть еще "исключительный" гость (м.р.).  Можно добавить в список - для полноты.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова - да, спасибо. Был ведь у меня, куда-то исчез потом... Вместе с "путь".